# I can't change font awesome's style

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I downloaded a web site template from this [link](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page202/boss). How can I change the icon's style in the navigation menu of the index.html page?

```
<i class="fa fa-home" style="color:black; font-size:48px"></i><a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

This didnt work

So I introduced the style through a new class "fa-home-a"

```
.fa-home-a {
color:black;
}
```

and changed my html to this

```
<i class="fa fa-home fa-home-a"></i><a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

but this didnt work as either

Comment: What element are trying to change the style? If it's 'Home', the closing </i> needs to go after the </a>

Comment: @curt I just want change color of font awesome's icon, not "Home" link

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the modified class use the original class that is fa-home and apply external css which is

`.fa-home {
color:black;
font-size:80px;
}`

If this does not works then you will have to give the refrence of the parent class

Answer (score 0):

```
 <i class="fa fa-home" style="color:black; font-size:48px"></i><a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

I want to say that the problem is coming from the inline-style reference, there is a missing semi-colon ;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked that at my code. Problem isn't that :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I added "color" property to following piece of code

```
#hornav li [class^="fa-"]:before,
#hornav li [class*=" fa-"]:before {
...
color:#ffd602;
}
```